# Unbinding ckeditor events added with ckeditor.tools.bind

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Our web app creates and destroys ckeditor editors regularly. We are seeing a memory leak in Chrome and after profiling it seems the references to ckeditor are being held onto due to a call to ckeditor.tools.bind. Should editor.destroy remove these bindings? If not, is there a way to remove them myself?

Example code that exhibits the problem(time outs added to see if timing is the issue)

```
var editor;

    function replaceDiv() {
        if ( editor ) {
            editor.destroy();
        }
        setTimeout(function() { 
            editor = CKEDITOR.replace(document.getElementById("editable2"));
            setTimeout( function() { replaceDiv()}, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: In theory it should, but if some plugin is attaching events to a global object like CKEDITOR each time that it's created and it doesn't take care itself of cleaning up, then this kind of problem might happen.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it's related to the bindings, I think it's something to do with the fact we remove the elements from the DOM immediately after calling destroy

Comment: Certainly that could be a problem. I'm not sure that the destroy method is synchronous, and if it finds a problem it might stop without showing any error. Can you try to remove the elements in a 1 second timeout, just to check?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem was that I had another editor that is always active. It seems that ckeditor does some special housekeeping when the last editor is destroyed. Since we never reached zero editors, this housekeeping didn't kick in. I'll create and destroy our other editor as required, since it's not always visible